# If statement in array value Codeigniter

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, google-maps

I have array value form marker option "info_window". I'm using Codeigniter and Google Maps v3 library. Is it possible to include if statement to a value?
My code and option for if statement:

```
 $marker['info_window'] =
                            '<div class="info_window">' . "$f->title" . '<br/>' .
                            '<div class="pin_icon"></div>' .
                            "$f->address" . '<br/>' . 

if ($f->www != 0){echo $f->www, '<br/>'} .


                            '<div class="phone_icon"></div>' .
                            "$f->phone" . '<br/>' . '<hr>' .
                            '<div class="directions_driving"><a href="'.site_url()."">Pokaži pot - avto</a></div>' . '<br/>' .
                            '<div class="directions_walking"><a href="'.site_url()."">Pokaži pot - hoja</a></div>' .
                            '<div class="street_view_icon"><a href="'.site_url()."">Street view</a></div>' .
                            '</div><br/>';
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue. I defined variable with if before so i just variable inside array value.